# Change column property from NOT NULL to NULL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, null

I am running on phpmyadmin and need to change the value of a column so it can accept NULL values. Any help on how to do it would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `modify column` on the original column definition:

- First use `SHOW CREATE TABLE columnname;` and find the original column definition
- Then change that definition, so that instead of `NOT NULL` it contains e.g. `DEFAULT NULL` or nothing of that sort
- Now use `MODIFY COLUMN columnname [changed definition]` to commit this to the DB

Comment: It responded with "table clumnname doesn´t exist"